# How does Heroku's _preboot_ feature work when changing config variables?

Tags: heroku

Using Heroku's PAAS it is understood that changing config variables causes a new release and the preboot feature handles typical releases by starting new dynos before switching over request handling. What is unclear from looking at [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot#deploying-with-preboot) for deployments with preboot, is how preboot works when just changing the config/environment variables. 
Can someone confirm that there the behaviour when changing config vars is identical the a normal release?

Answer (score 1):

Upon re-reading the documentation it does appear that the dyno preboot process does apply when updating config vars - so there is no gap in processing requests.